# Google adsense console error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, adsense

I have implemented the google adsense code in my angular project through a directive. The ads seem to be showing up. But, sometimes I get a console error `ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable adsbygoogle`and the ads space is blank.
Anyone faced this issue? Appreciate if someone could point out the solution to this issue.

Directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('googleAdsense', function() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            templateUrl: "directives/adsense.html",
            controller: function() {
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxx"></ins>
```

Index.html

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post your try out code